# How to analyze crawl results

Tags: python, word-cloud

I crawled and saved the user's website usage lists.
I want to analyze the results of the crawl, but I wonder how there is a way.
First of all, what I thought was Word Cloud.
I am looking for a way to track user's personal preferences with user's computer history.

I want a way to visualize personal tendencies, etc. at a glance. Or I'm looking for a way to find out if there's no risk of suicide or addiction as a result of the search.
thank you.

Comment: I will use matplotlib and textrank thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize data and make analysis on it matplotlib would be good start , again it depends a lot on your data. Matplotlib and seaborn are plotting libraries that are good for representing quantitative data and get some basic analysis at least.